# Jquery Remove White Space

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to remove unwanted whitespace & symbol from content.

using:

```js
$('.infora .price .amount').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('£', '');
  return text.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="infora">
  <p class="price"><span class="amount">
                          13.95                          </span>
  </p>
</section>
```

The pound sign get's removed fine but the white space still remain's.

Any idea's?

Comment: return text.replace('£', '').replace(/\s+/g, '');

Comment: @JaromandaX if you post an answer I will give it to you as you are the one who got it on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\s+`, this will remove all space characters. e.g. tabs. Using `/ /g` will only remove space characters.

```
return text.replace('£', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Thanks to @JaromandaX
```

Chain both `replace` statements. As you cannot return twice from a function. The second statement after `return` will not execute.

**Edit**

You can also combine the two `replace` into one `regex`.

```
return text.replace(/[£\s]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return twice in a function. Also, for you case, [**trim()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is useful

```
$('.infora .price .amount').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('£', '').trim();
});
```

```js
$('.infora .price .amount').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace('£', '').trim();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="infora">
  <p class="price"><span class="amount">
                          £13.95                          </span>
  </p>
</section>
```